# SQL simple query on multiple linked servers & databases

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this simple SQL query in SSMS `select * from dbo.table1 where sucode = 'a002'`

I am trying to learn how to run this on all linked servers on databases ending in `%live`

I've never done this before and what I have seen online hasn't really helped.

I know I need to have `QUOTENAME(d.name, '''') ....WHERE NAME like '%live'` for the database name and possibly the same for the server? Or maybe an `OPENQUERY` for the server? Or a link?

If anyone has a template they use or any advise that would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: *"I am trying to learn how to run this on all linked servers on databases ending in %live"* This feels like a double barrelled question. Are you saying you want to run the above query against multiple databases on multiple instances? What is the end goal here then? What do you achieve from doing this?

Comment: @Larnu sorry for the confusion....in this example, I want to find every `a002` in column `sucode` in all of the `table1` in dbs that end in `%live`. All of these dbs have `table1` in them. I know I can just run this by manually doing `SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY([server1], 'select * from Xlive.dbo.table1 where sucode = ''a002''')` and then again for `Ylive` in `server1` and then run for db `Xlive` in `server2` and so on, but there are a lot of servers and dbs so am seeing if there is a better way? I hope this is clear enough

Comment: You can run a query against multiple instances at the same time using registered servers, but to then run that against multiple (dynamic) databases would require dynamic SQL; and I'm not even sure if that'll work for that type of query (I've never used dynamic queries with registered server groups). This feels like an [xy problem](http://xyproblem.info) if I am honest.

Comment: Didn't you ask something similar to his in your last question 2 days ago ?

Comment: @Larnu thank you for your input, though its not really an XY problem as I am wanting help with both the server part and db part as I have tried to explain and just provided my thoughts on how it could work and asking for advise. Apologies if I have not been clear.

Comment: @Squirrel can this be used for all linked servers as well as particular dbs? This is why I have asked a new question as didn't want to confuse/add to the previous existing question as thought it was separate. If needed I can close this question and ask on the other one, but wasn't sure if that was allowed?

Comment: This is why I asked what your end goal is, @PeterK . What are you planning to do with this data? If you have a design like this, where you have multiple databases on a single instance with the same object(s) it tends to denote a design flaw in my opinion. This seems to then be compounded by doing it again at instance level.

Comment: @Larnu to give you an example on how this works in practice, I have multiple companies around the world on different servers. Each company is it's own database. Now if I wanted to see our worldwide spend with supplier "XYZ", how would I do that? I would either need to look at each db on each server one at a time or, do what I am asking for help with, and have one query to search all servers and all databases on the same named table in each db that has this information for company XYZ (hence me asking for specific database names and not all like `master` and `model` etc). Hopefully that helps.

Comment: This is why I said it sounds like a design flaw; seems like you should have a central data warehouse instance for such information, and the servers should be *pushing* that data to your data warehouse instance.

Comment: I see....maybe this question should really be about how to create one server/db that links all servers & dbs together? Times like this I wish I should have become a chef! Thanks @Larnu for your assistance.

Comment: That would make sense, @PeterK . Trying to do this type of analysis with multiple instances, that also have separate databases is not going to scale well. You'll going to likely need dynamic SQL, that then executes Dynamic SQL if you want to run those statements from a single instance. That is going to be far from easy to maintain; especially if you are unfamiliar with such techniques (which it appears you aren't, as you'd likely have demonstrated something in the question if you were). Getting the data in an easily consumable and central location seems a far better plan.

Answer (score 0):

You can use undocumented stored procedure MS_ForeachDb to execute the query against each database. You can use `sys.servers` to get the list of linked servers and run them against each linked server.

[Read MS_ForeachDB](https://weblogs.sqlteam.com/joew/2008/08/27/60700/)
[Read about sys.servers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-servers-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

```sql
SELECT 'SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(' + name + ',''EXECUTE master.sys.sp_MSforeachdb ''USE [?];select * from dbo.table1 where sucode = ''a002'''')' 
FROM sys.servers WHERE is_linked = 1; -- avoid pulling from local server
```

Note: Using undocumented procedures is not recommended. [Read more on this using undocumented procedures bad practice](https://sqlblog.org/2020/05/12/bad-habits-to-kick-relying-on-undocumented-behavior)

Comment: There's little point doing `USE ?` and then following that with a `SELECT` using 3 part naming. ;)